# button restriction alerts popover titles

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following scenario with the form bellow:

```
<form action="action.php">
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="input2">
  <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover 
  title" data-content="You don't have permission to press button">Button</button>
</form>
```

I need some Javascript code that says:
if input1=input2 submit form else popover title saying "You don't have permission ". I tried some stuff based on some search on the internet but it didn't really work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.